# Java regexp date string

Tags: java, regex

I need help creating a regular expression that will parse the following string :

```
09-22-11 12:58:40       SEVERE       ...ractBlobAodCommand:104           -   IllegalStateException: version:1316719189017 not found in recent history                             Dump: /data1/aafghani/dev/devamir/logs/dumps/22i125840.dump
```

The most difficult part for me is parsing out the date.  I'm not really an expert on Java regular expressions - any help is appreciated.

Comment: What fields do you want? What should the fields be from the example? How does the data vary?

Comment: Hi TJ - I'd like the date, the severity, the classname and line number, the exception message, and the dump file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is a bit misleading as it implies the need to
>   parse the date into `java.util.Date` object or similar. The real
>   question is how to split up the input data into the desired fields:
>
> - date
> - level
> - location name & line
> - exception name & message
> - dump file

This is one solution using a regular expression.

```java
String pattern = "^(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})" // date
    + "[ ]+(SEVERE|WARNING|INFO|CONFIG|FINE|FINER|FINEST)" // level
    + "[ ]+([^:]+):(\\d+)" // location name, location line
    + "[ ]+-[ ]+([^:]+): (.*?)" // exception name, exception message
    + "[ ]+Dump: ([a-zA-Z0-9\\./]+)" // dump
    + "$";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
String input = "09-22-11 12:58:40       SEVERE       ...ractBlobAodCommand:104           -   IllegalStateException: version:1316719189017 not found in recent history                             Dump: /data1/aafghani/dev/devamir/logs/dumps/22i125840.dump";
Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);
assertTrue(m.matches());
assertSame(7, m.groupCount());
for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
  System.out.format("[%d] \"%s\"%n", i, m.group(i));
}
```

**Output**

```
[1] "09-22-11 12:58:40"
[2] "SEVERE"
[3] "...ractBlobAodCommand"
[4] "104"
[5] "IllegalStateException"
[6] "version:1316719189017 not found in recent history"
[7] "/data1/aafghani/dev/devamir/logs/dumps/22i125840.dump"
```

Comment: How can I make the dump file optional TJ?  is it with the ( ) ?

Comment: + "[ ]+(?:(?:Dump: )([a-zA-Z0-9\\./]+))?" // dump

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse a date with regular expressions. Instead use a SimpleDateFormat object.

e.g.,

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Foo001 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test = "    09-22-11 12:58:40       SEVERE       ...ractBlobAodCommand:104           -   IllegalStateException: version:1316719189017 not found in recent history                             Dump: /data1/aafghani/dev/devamir/logs/dumps/22i125840.dump";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^\\s+)\\d[\\d -:]+\\d+(?=\\s+)");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
      if (matcher.find()) {
         String dateString = matcher.group();

         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss");

         try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(date);
         } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }


   }
}
```

Comment: But first I need to get the date object parsed out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that's what you need? I'd consider splitting the string on delimiters or columns and using existing date parsing libs to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract the date (without timestamp) out:

```
^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

in java, it should be

```
String regex = "^\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for the date:

^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d